# Quick access in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring

I need a fast way to go to a specific folder, in Package Explorer, of Spring Tool Suite 4.
Ie, a shorcut.
Maybe something like Quick access in Windows Explorer.

Any help will be much appreciated.

What did I try and what was I expecting?
I searched the web, expecting to find a solution.
What actually happened?
I found nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand what is hard to tell?  I need a quick way to open a specific folder in the Package Explorer.